# Eyebeam softphone is not able to place a call with correct number provided from html page followed with sip value in href tag

Tags: html, registry, protocols, href, sip

I have installed and configured EyeBeam softphone, and created a link in html page to place a call from eyeBeam softphone on only Windows platform, below is the html:

```
<a href="sip:xxxxxx">xxxxxx</a>
```

I have also configured the setting in Windows protocol registry for sip, as below:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\CounterPath\eyeBeam 1.5\eyeBeam.exe" -dial="%1"
```

The problem is when I click on link, it is taking all the string to eyeBeam followed with "sip" word also, I want number only to dial.

I have searched a lot on this, there may have many parameters to remove sip word, but not getting any permanent solution on this.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case with the Eyebeam softphone, I have modified my link with:

```
<a href="sip:xxxxxx@xxxxxx">xxxxxx</a>
```

and this works for me, the registry command is same for sip protocol as mentioned in my question.

Below are some of the links I referred:

https://medium.com/@m.bhavsar6/custom-browser-protocol-for-windows-application-openrdp-708cd48aa387

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/application-management/change-registry-values-permissions

Comment: Hi, can you help/share us with the registry entry for eyebeam & an example link? to save my time as well as for others too

Comment: it require nothing all modern browsers already support that example `<a href='sip:+coutrycodemobilenumber;user=youruser'>`; this is to just to help others looking for quick solutions